# Where can I download nhibernate.caches.syscache 3.1

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-caches

I've been looking over the internet and can't seem to find where I can download v3.1 of nhibernate.caches.syscache that works with NHibernate 3.1.0.4000.

I have version 3.0.0.4000 of the syscache, but is there a newer version?

Comment: I am looking for nhibernate syscache that is compatible with nhibernate 3.0 GA .  Can your 3.0.0.400 syscache do that ? Where can I download it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The official place is here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/NHibernate.Caches/
don't know however if your cache is officially mantained in that place, have a look.

Comment: thanks, i just read an older post that said it was in the contrib project and sure enough, it's there.